# How to import scss into index.html through webpack?

Tags: webpack, sass

Hello I use vue/cli@next, but now I need to make `<noscript></noscript>`
template design in the project.
So I cannot use .vue files.
I have

```
<body>
  <noscript>
    <div class="error-background"></div>
  </noscript>
  <div id=" app">
  </div>
</body>
```

and style that needs scss preprocessor, I can put it inline, but I also want to use cssMinimizerWebpackPlugin in this style and webpack scss loader to generate my css code.
How can I set up my project to make it possible? Or use special require...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you have a configured CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin and you need the code to be optimized by the plugin and loaded by the browser without JS.
The most correct solution would be to extract CSS using MiniCssExtractPlugin
If you're using vue/cli@next u can (**for example**, more info [vue docs css](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract)) make your code like this:

```
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename:"css/[name][id].css",
      chunkFilename:"css/[name][id].css",
      ignoreOrder: false,
      insert: "document.head.appendChild(linkTag)",
      attributes: {},
      linkType: "text/css",
      runtime: false,
      experimentalUseImportModule: undefined,
    },
    sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  },
```

and u also need to make multiple entry points for htmlWebpackPlugin
in Vue Cli 5 u can use [vue docs pages](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages)

```
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: ["src/main.ts", "styles/main.scss", "styles/error.scss"],
    },
  },
```

all these rules should be inside

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
//code here
})
```